# How can I get the last 50 elements in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
List<BtnCountViews> btnCountViewsList;
```

The BtnCountViews class looks like this:

```
public class BtnCountViews
{
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int BtnCount { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
}
```

The data has been added to the list in a sorted order already.

Can someone tell me how I can get just the last 50 elements? I am hoping it's possible with LINQ but I have not seen any examples on how to do this.

Comment: Try `btnCountViewsList.Skip(Math.Max(0, btnCountViewsList.Count() - n))` where `n` belongs to last n elements to retrieve with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just skip the first list's size minus 50.

```
        var list = new List<BtnCountViews>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new BtnCountViews() { BtnCount = i, DayOfYear = i, Views = i });
        }

        var last50 = list.Skip(list.Count - 50).ToList();
```